# How to assign datasource to gridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Iam creating a winform application and trying to assign a datasource to datagridview. Iam facing a little problem if anyone solves I will be really thankful. Please see the below query:-

```
var query = (from c in db.LineMaster
select new { c.OrderId, c.InvoiceNo, c.CustName }).ToList();
dgv.DataSource = query;
```

Above code works perfectly and display all the required data at runtime in datagridview. But when I try to get the last column to sum all values it shows nothing for example when I write the following code its shows nothing:-

```
if (dgv.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (i = 0; i <= dgv.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
               {
                   v_sum += Convert.ToDecimal(dgv.Rows[i].Cells["Col_Total"].Value);
                }
            }
```

The above query does not count rows of datagridview but stil display data in datagridview. 
So my question is that how can I get the rows by writing code like dgv.rows.count to further manipulate when assigning datasource to datagridview ???
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please tag this with the language you are using.

Comment: instead of column name specify columns number (like if last column is 4th column mention it , `dgv.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value` )

Comment: Thanks for the reply xpertgun, But its still not working. Actually I am creating datagridview columns programmatically, that's why I think its not getting column number. Do you have any other solution ???, Thanks.

Comment: your linq query doesn't have a column named 'Col_Total' so accessing it via dgv.Rows[i].Cells["Col_Total"].Value cannot work ... and your linq query returns only 3 columns so accessing the last column via dgv.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value as suggested by xpertgun cannot work either ... I think you should start by adding the column you want to sum to your linq query

Comment: Thanks to all, Actually when I assign rows to datagridview by using loop then I can easily get rows when writing dgv.rows.count. But when assigning data source directly to datagridview like dgv.Datasource = query.toList(); then I cannot count rows on datagridview. I think issue is now clear. Please give any other solution which count rows in datagridview .... Thanks.